# Android - PWA does not open in standalone mode with service worker

Tags: android, google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

While developing a Progressive-Web-App the following Problem occurred:

*Standalone mode works perfectly without including the service worker - but does NOT work with.*

- Without Service-Worker a2hs (added to Homescreen) PWA gets correctly started in `"standalone"`-Mode.
- After adding the Service-Worker (a2hs + installed / Web-APK) PWA opens new Tab in new Chrome-Window.

**Chrome-PWA-Audit:**

[image: Chrome PWA Lighthouse Test]

**login_mobile_tablet.jsf / include service worker:**

```
<script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('../serviceWorker.js', {scope: "/application/"})
          /* also tried ".", "/", "./" as scope value */
            .then(function(registration) {
                console.log('Service worker registration successful, scope is: ', registration.scope);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Service worker registration failed, error: ', error);
            });
    }
</script>
```

**serviceWorker.js:**

```
var cacheName = 'pwa-cache';

// A list of local resources we always want to be cached.
var filesToCache = [
    'QS1.xhtml',
    'pdf.xhtml',
    'QS1.jsf',
    'pdf.jsf',
    'login_pages/login_mobile_tablet.jsf',
    'login_pages/login_mobile_tablet.xhtml'
];

// The install handler takes care of precaching the resources we always need.
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {

    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
            return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
        })
    );
})

// The activate handler takes care of cleaning up old caches.
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

// The fetch handler serves responses for same-origin resources from a cache.
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {

    // Workaround for error:
    // TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'ServiceWorkerGlobalScope': 'only-if-cached' can be set only with 'same-origin' mode
    // see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48463483/what-causes-a-failed-to-execute-fetch-on-serviceworkerglobalscope-only-if
    if (event.request.cache === 'only-if-cached' && event.request.mode !== 'same-origin')
        return;

    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request, {ignoreSearch: true})
            .then(response => {
                return response || fetch(event.request);
            })
    );
});
```

**manifest.json:**

```
{
   "name":"[Hidden]",
   "short_name":"[Hidden]",
   "start_url":"/application/login_pages/login_mobile_tablet.jsf",
   "scope":".",
   "display":"standalone",
   "background_color":"#4688B8",
   "theme_color":"#4688B8",
   "orientation":"landscape",
   "icons":[
      {
         "src":"javax.faces.resource/images/icons/qsc_128.png.jsf",
         "sizes":"128x128",
         "type":"image/png"
      },
      {
         "src":"javax.faces.resource/images/icons/qsc_144.png.jsf",
         "sizes":"144x144",
         "type":"image/png"
      },
      {
         "src":"javax.faces.resource/images/icons/qsc_152.png.jsf",
         "sizes":"152x152",
         "type":"image/png"
      },
      {
         "src":"javax.faces.resource/images/icons/qsc_192.png.jsf",
         "sizes":"192x192",
         "type":"image/png"
      },
      {
         "src":"javax.faces.resource/images/icons/qsc_256.png.jsf",
         "sizes":"256x256",
         "type":"image/png"
      },
      {
         "src":"javax.faces.resource/images/icons/qsc_512.png.jsf",
         "sizes":"512x512",
         "type":"image/png"
      }
   ]
}
```

The following questions / answers were considered - but no solution was found:

- [PWA wont open in standalone mode on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46941802/pwa-wont-open-in-standalone-mode-on-android)
- [WebAPK ignores display:standalone flag for PWA running on local network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51748668/webapk-ignores-displaystandalone-flag-for-pwa-running-on-local-network)
- [PWA deployed in node.js running in Standalone mode on Android and iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677716/pwa-deployed-in-node-js-running-in-standalone-mode-on-android-and-ios)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Technical Background**
The Moment you add your Service-Worker (along all other PWA-Requirements) your App gets created as an Real PWA - with Web-APK getting installed.
Therefore you also need to use Default-HTTPS-Port 443 - make sure you use a valid HTTPS-Certificate.
Before adding the Service-Worker, this mandatory requirement was missing so your PWA was NOT installed and therefore needed less other requirements to be displayed in `"standalone-mode"`.
It's just a shame that this is nowhere documented... and we had to "find out" for ourselves.

**Short-List of Mandatory Requirements for "Installable Web-APK":**

(As we could not find a full List, i try to include all Points)

- Registered Service-Worker (default-implementation like yours is enough)
- manifest.json (yours is valid)
- https with valid certificate
- https default-port (443, eg. https://yourdomain.com/test/)
- ... for the rest just check chrome audit tool (HINT: you don't need to pass all requirements - your web-apk should work when switching to https-default-port)

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this for many hours and checked everything including that the correct assetlinks key was served on my website from `./well-known/assetlinks.json`, nothing worked. Finally, I tested my website against https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator. I had used Microsoft's PWABuilder UI to generate the APK for me, and turns out that I was missing a "www" in my website name, when specifying the host.

**Correct host**: [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com)

**Incorrect host**: mywebsite.com

Hope that this can help others.