# URL bar still showing after setting up TWA and deployed to store

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I set up a PWA app with TWA following the google developer documentation about it

- tried manifest.json display property to fullscreen
- all stackoverflow answers

My assetlinks.json file

```
 [{
      "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
      "target": {
        "namespace": "android_app",
        "package_name": "pk.sastaticket.staging",
        "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
        ["12:57:39:74:FA:3D:64:A7:37:F2:A1:7A:2F:DD:73:AB:D0:82:29:D4:47:A9:B5:5F:53:6B:50:FE:E2:21:1B:73"]
      }
    },
    {
      "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
      "target": {
        "namespace": "web",
        "site": "https://staging.sastaticket.pk"
      }
    },
    {
      "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
      "target": {
        "namespace": "android_app",
        "package_name": "pk.sastaticket.staging",
        "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
        ["12:57:39:74:FA:3D:64:A7:37:F2:A1:7A:2F:DD:73:AB:D0:82:29:D4:47:A9:B5:5F:53:6B:50:FE:E2:21:1B:73"]
      }
    }]
```

Comment: Desktop or Mobile or Same on Both? Does your site URL have a port number in it, or is it a sub-domain? I think I have seen some issues with those in the past.

Comment: it's a subdomain.

Comment: One thing to look at if you control that server - the HTTPS default port 443. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53764921/android-pwa-does-not-open-in-standalone-mode-with-service-worker

Comment: Also perhaps search on this term - Standalone PWA

Comment: Can you update the post with the contents of your `AndroidManifest.xml`, `build.gradle` and `strings.xml`? This help checking if the Android side of the Digital Asset Links configuration is complete.